# how to insert a youtube link in text file using python

Tags: python

> I am basically building a CLI application where im asking user file path for text file and some youtube links as to insert it in that particular text file
> and then with random selection , im reading the youtube link and opening via web browser library
> but im getting a error , here

```
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "d:\useless folder(only for coding use)\docx folder\for_cmd.py", line 18, in youtube_selecter
    file = open_file.readlines()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

> my code is below

```
import webbrowser
import typer
import os 
import random



app = typer.Typer()
@app.command()
def youtube_selecter():
  ask_filepath = None
  while not os.path.exists(ask_filepath):
    ask_filepath = input("enter a empty file filepath for saving youtube links")
  ask_youtube_link = None
  while ask_youtube_link != "quit":
    ask_youtube_link = input("enter youtube link")
    with open(ask_filepath,"r+") as f:
      file = f.readlines()
      f.write(ask_youtube_link + "\n")
    if ask_youtube_link == "quit":
      break
  ask_user = input("do you want to read the file")
  if ask_user == "yes":
    print(file)
  else:
    print("ok")
  random_choice = random.choices(f)
  while ask_user != "yes":
    ask_user = input(f"do you want to view {random_choice}")
    if ask_user == "yes":
      open = webbrowser.open(random_choice)
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app()
```

> so can help to solve this issue?

> you can copy/paste and check it
> you can copy/paste and check it

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The path you're providing within the file system does not exist hence 'NoneType'.